# How to dynamically bind the website data using AnguarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, single-page-application

Unlike .Net where we have .Net resource files for storing the strings Is there any best way to handle in SPA using AngularJS? I am wondering where to store the site's content using AngularJS and I also need to handle localization using this. Can someone point me to online materials or plunker examples?

I am talking about the website's entire content. Where is this content stored in SPA like AngularJS? I worked with .Net and I know that website content is stored in RESX files.

Comment: did not understand your question ? what you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 0):

What I think you should do is create a single page app and play around with how it all works.

This example is a good start:
https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Comment: I am talking about the website's entire content. Where is this content stored in SPA like AngularJS? I worked with .Net and I know that website content is stored in RESX files.

Comment: can someone pls respond?